# OL3, pixel based zoomify with vector overlay incorrectly offset

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Asked at [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172730), but nothing forthcoming, hoping someone here might have ideas. Sorry for the cross post. Am updating a project from OL2, where what I'm attempting worked fine. Project isn't a map, it's images of text documents converted to zoom tiles.

Added a vector layer of polygons that represent the coordinates of terms/phrases in text found in the OCR text.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u95cx7vm/2/) shows a page with highlighting for 3 hits on the term "texas". Note the position of the terms is correct on one axis, but simply too high on the screen. Again, same pixel coords worked in OL2.

Excerpt from fiddle:

```
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
          features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: source
            }),
            new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource,
                style: styleFunction
            })
          ],
          target: 'zoom',
          view: new ol.View({
            projection: proj,
            constrainRotation: 0,
            center: imgCenter,
            zoom: 0,
            // constrain the center: center cannot be set outside
            // this extent
            extent: [0, -imgHeight, imgWidth, 0]
          })
        });
```

Problem seems to be related to the projection, extent, or centering. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using wrong coordinates. I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/y3wfxdxr/) which you can draw a box around a text and you'll see the coordinates on top.

So if you change for example your coordinates to:

```
var geojsonObject = {
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'features': [
  {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
      'type': 'MultiPolygon',
      'coordinates': [

      [[[1849.90, -2385.40], [1849.90, -2619.07], [2258.83, -2619.07], [2258.83, -2385.40]]]

      ]
    }
  }
  ]
};
```

The polygon will be where you want.